# Prevent ReadFile or ReadAll from reading EOF

Tags: go, readfile

I start learning Go and I am a bit puzzled by the fact it includes the EOF when using the [ioutil.ReadFile](https://gowalker.org/io/ioutil#ReadFile) function. I want, for example, to read a file and parse all its lines on a field separator.

Sample input File:

```
CZG;KCZG;some text
EKY;KEKY;some text
A50;KA50;some text
UKY;UCFL;some text
MIC;KMIC;some text
K2M;K23M;some text
```

This is what I do to read and parse that file:

```
import(
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "io/ioutil"
    "strings"
    )

func main() {  
    /* Read file */
    airportsFile := "/path/to/file/ad_iata"
    content, err := ioutil.ReadFile(airportsFile)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    /* split content on EOL */
    lines := strings.Split(string(content), "\n")

    /* split line on field separator ; */
    for _, line := range lines {
        lineSplit := strings.Split(line, ";")
        fmt.Println(lineSplit)
    }
}
```

The [string.Split](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Split) function adds a empty element at the end of the lineSplit slice when it sees the EOF (nothing to parse). Therefore, if I want to access the second index of that slice (`lineSplit[1]`) I run into a `panic: runtime error: index out of range`. I have to restrict the range by doing this

```
/* split line on field separator ; */
lenLines := len(lines) -1
for _, line := range lines[:lenLines] {
    lineSplit := strings.Split(line, ";")
    fmt.Println(lineSplit[1])
}
```

Is there a better way if I want to keep using ReadFile for its terseness ?

The same problem occurs when using [ioutil.ReadAll](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll)

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as an "EOF byte" or "EOF character". What you are seeing is probably caused by a line break character (`'\n'`) at the very end of the file.

To read a file line by line, it's more idiomatic to use `bufio.Scanner` instead:

```
file, err := os.Open(airportsFile)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer file.Close()

scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
for scanner.Scan() {
    line := scanner.Text()
    // ... use line as you please ...
}

if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

And this actually addresses your problem, because `Scanner` will read the final newline without starting a new line, as evidenced by [this playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/Db99wO9dK_).

Comment: There is no trailing `\n` at the end of the file. Your solution with `bufio.Scanner` works fine indeed, but I just wondered if there were a option to prevent ioutil.ReadFile from adding a empty slice when it sees EOF. If there is none, I'll use bufio. Thanks.

Comment: How did you verify that there's no trailing newline? Some editors don't actually show these as a blank line, but add them silently anyway. Try `od -tc /path/to/file/ad_iata` and see.

Comment: I stand corrected. There IS a trailing `\n` at the end of the last line. That makes the behaviour of `ioutil.ReadFile` more logical to me. I learned something from you answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Your input File seeems to be CSV file, so you can use `encoding/csv`

```
airportsFile := "/path/to/file/ad_iata"
content, err := os.Open(airportsFile)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
r := csv.NewReader(content)
r.Comma = ';'
records, err := r.ReadAll()  /* split line on field separator ; */
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println(records)
```

which looks terse enough for me and provide correct output

[[CZG KCZG some text] [EKY KEKY some text] [A50 KA50 some text] [UKY UCFL some text] [MIC KMIC some text] [K2M K23M some text]]

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`scanner.Err()`](https://golang.org/src/bufio/scan.go?s=3814:3843#L80) to check for errors on file read.

```
// Err returns the first non-EOF error that was encountered by the Scanner.
func (s *Scanner) Err() error {
    if s.err == io.EOF {
        return nil
    }
    return s.err
}
```

In general in go the idiomatic way to read and parse a file is to use `bufio.NewScanner` which accept as an input parameter the file to read and returns a new `Scanner`.

Considering the above remarks here is a way you can read and parse a file:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    input, err := os.Open("example.txt")

    if err != nil {
        panic("Error happend during opening the file. Please check if file exists!")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    defer input.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(input)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        line := scanner.Text()
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", line)
    }
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "reading input:", err)
    }    
}
```